# Boolean expression minimization

Tags: boolean-expression

Is there anyway to make this expression with another gates (especially with nand, xor, nor). I almost tried every combination but I couldn't find. Allways one output is wrong.
~A~BC + AB~C

Comment: Is this meant to be ((NOT A, AND NOT B AND C) OR (A AND B AND NOT C))? Or is meant to be ((NOT A OR NOT B OR C) OR (A OR B OR NOT C))? Or is it some other expression?

Comment: first one @David

Answer (score 0):

You'll need 5 gates for this, 2 `NANDs`, 2 `ANDs` and 1 `OR`.

Run A and B into the first `NAND`, and put the output of that into the `AND`, along with C.

Then, into the second `NAND`, just put C on it's own. Then, the output of this `NAND` goes into the second `AND`, along with A and B.

The output of the 2 `AND` gates then goes into the `OR`, which will make the expression you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Truth table

```
A   B   C  ~A  ~B  ~C    ~A~BC  AB~C   ~A~BC + AB~C
0   0   0   1   1   1      0      0          0 
0   0   1   1   1   0      1      0          1 
0   1   0   1   0   1      0      0          0 
0   1   1   1   0   0      0      0          0 
1   0   0   0   1   1      0      0          0 
1   0   1   0   1   0      0      0          0 
1   1   0   0   0   1      0      1          1 
1   1   1   0   0   0      0      0          0
```

So you need 2 `AND` gates and 1 `OR` gate. Now replace `AND` gates with `NAND` gates:

```
A   B   C  ~A  ~B  ~C    NAND(~A,~B,C)  NAND(A,B,~C)      ?
0   0   0   1   1   1          1             1            0 
0   0   1   1   1   0          0             1            1 
0   1   0   1   0   1          1             1            0 
0   1   1   1   0   0          1             1            0 
1   0   0   0   1   1          1             1            0 
1   0   1   0   1   0          1             1            0 
1   1   0   0   0   1          1             0            1 
1   1   1   0   0   0          1             1            0
```

Which gate make `1 1 -> 0` and `0 1 -> 1`? `XOR` gate.

Simple answer: `~A~BC + AB~C = NAND(~A,~B,C) ⊕ NAND(A,B,~C)`